# JavaScript onload function not executing

Tags: javascript, function

I have a problem, so lets go straight to the point, my function isn't executing.

Code:

```
<body class="addbackground" onload="compareDate()">
   <script type="text/javascript">
var season5 = [
"2014,09,13,22,00,00", //1
"2014,09,20,22,00,00", //2
"2014,09,27,22,00,00", //3
"2014,10,3,22,00,00", //4
"2014,10,10,22,00,00", //5
"2014,10,17,22,00,00", //6
"2014,10,24,22,00,00", //7
"2014,11,2,22,00,00", //8
//MidSeason break
"2015,01,9,22,00,00", //9
"2015,01,16,22,00,00", //10
"2015,01,23,22,00,00", //11
"2015,02,2,22,00,00", //12
"2015,02,9,22,00,00", //13
"2015,02,16,22,00,00", //14
"2015,02,23,22,00,00", //15
"2015,02,30,22,00,00", //16
];
console.log("Array");

function compareDate() {
console.log("Function fired");
var today = new Date();
var todayDate = today.getFullYear() + "," + today.getMonth() + "," + today.getDay() + "," + today.getHours() + ","+ today.getMinutes() + "," + today.getSeconds();
  if(Date.parse(todayDate) > Date.parse(season5[0])) {
    document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "111";
console.log("111");
}
else {
document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "222";
console.log("222");
}
}
</script>
<div id="testDate">Oeps...</div>
</body>
```

I have to type more text blah blah... I still have to write some more...

Comment: Why are you creating a date, converting it to a string and then parsing it in again? Just use Date.now().

Comment: There's nothing here that would explain why the function isn't being called. You'll need to post an example that actually shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code, made few fixes like we need to use getDate() instead of getDay(), (today.getMonth() + 1)  and handled season5[0].

http://jsfiddle.net/sahilbatla/p7rfcLgt/

```
<script>
 function compareDate() {
    console.log("Function fired");

    var today = new Date();
    var todayDate = today.getFullYear() + "," + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "," + today.getDate() + "," + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    console.log(todayDate)
    if (Date.parse(todayDate) > Date.parse('12/20/2014')) {
        document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "111";
        console.log("111");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "222";
        console.log("222");
    }
}
</script>
<body class="addbackground" onload="compareDate()">
    <div id="testDate"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing some errors, but it still isn't executing :(

Comment: did you try the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe somewhere else.I created this fiddle to show you that the function executes fine.

[**See it work**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3kvvamy/1/)

Code:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<div id="testDate">Oeps...</div>
<script>
    var season5 = [
"2014,09,13,22,00,00", //1
"2014,09,20,22,00,00", //2
"2014,09,27,22,00,00", //3
"2014,10,3,22,00,00", //4
"2014,10,10,22,00,00", //5
"2014,10,17,22,00,00", //6
"2014,10,24,22,00,00", //7
"2014,11,2,22,00,00", //8
//MidSeason break
"2015,01,9,22,00,00", //9
"2015,01,16,22,00,00", //10
"2015,01,23,22,00,00", //11
"2015,02,2,22,00,00", //12
"2015,02,9,22,00,00", //13
"2015,02,16,22,00,00", //14
"2015,02,23,22,00,00", //15
"2015,02,30,22,00,00", //16
];
function compareDate() {
    alert("What do you mean it doesn't run??");
    console.log("Function fired");

    var today = new Date();
    var todayDate = today.getFullYear() + "," + today.getMonth() + "," + today.getDay() + "," + today.getHours() + "," + today.getMinutes() + "," + today.getSeconds();
    if (Date.parse(todayDate) > Date.parse(season5[0])) {
        document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "111";
        console.log("111");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "222";
        console.log("222");
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have an other `console.log` inside the same script tag, and that one is just printing to the console

Comment: Like @Juhana said, post more code so we can help you further.

Comment: That's your entire code? Where is you html tag?

Comment: Updated the code and it works just fine. The console logs fine, too

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body onload="compareDate()">

<script>
var season5 = [
"2014,09,13,22,00,00", //1
"2014,09,20,22,00,00", //2
"2014,09,27,22,00,00", //3
"2014,10,3,22,00,00", //4
"2014,10,10,22,00,00", //5
"2014,10,17,22,00,00", //6
"2014,10,24,22,00,00", //7
"2014,11,2,22,00,00", //8
//MidSeason break
"2015,01,9,22,00,00", //9
"2015,01,16,22,00,00", //10
"2015,01,23,22,00,00", //11
"2015,02,2,22,00,00", //12
"2015,02,9,22,00,00", //13
"2015,02,16,22,00,00", //14
"2015,02,23,22,00,00", //15
"2015,02,30,22,00,00", //16
];
console.log("Array");

function compareDate() {
console.log("Function fired");
var today = new Date();
var todayDate = today.getFullYear() + "," + today.getMonth() + "," + today.getDay() + "," + today.getHours() + ","+ today.getMinutes() + "," + today.getSeconds();
  if(Date.parse(todayDate) > Date.parse(season5[0])) {
    document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "111";
console.log("111");
}
else {
document.getElementById("testDate").innerHTML = "222";
console.log("222");
}
}
</script>
<div id="testDate"></div>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

try this, it works for me